# Group and get bigger date from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, data-manipulation

First please let me know if I'm not explaining well.

**Problem**

I'm having an issue, this is my object an code, which is grouped by `LevelId`

Code for group that give the below object **:**

```js
function groupBy(arr, property) {
  return arr.reduce(function (memo, x) {
    if (!memo[x[property]]) { memo[x[property]] = []; }
    memo[x[property]].push(x);
    return memo;
  }, {});
}
let o = groupBy(levels, 'LevelId');
var result = Object.keys(o).map((key) => [Number(key), o[key]]);
```

**My Object**

```json
[
    [
        2,
        [
            {
                "Id": 5037,
                "Date1": "2016-06-22T22:00:00Z",
                "LevelId": 2,
                "ParticipantId": 9915,
                "ID": 5037
            },
            {
                "Id": 5722,
                "Date1": "2017-08-11T22:00:00Z",
                "LevelId": 2,
                "ParticipantId": 9915,
                "ID": 5722
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        4,
        [
            {
                "Id": 5720,
                "Date1": "2017-08-09T22:00:00Z",
                "LevelId": 4,
                "ParticipantId": 9915,
                "ID": 5720
            },
            {
                "Id": 5721,
                "Date1": "2017-08-10T22:00:00Z",
                "LevelId": 4,
                "ParticipantId": 9915,
                "ID": 5721
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

My Problem now is picking the bigger date for each `LevelId`, In this case 2 and 4 and have only that specific item.

**My Attempt**

Before I had this code which works great but only for one level

```js
let isLast = levels[0];
  for (let date of levels) {
    if (moment(date.Date1) > moment(isLast.Date1)) {
      isLast = date;
    }
  }
```

For this object

```json
[
    {
        "Id": 5037,
        "Date1": "2016-06-22T22:00:00Z",
        "LevelId": 2,
        "ParticipantId": 9915,
        "ID": 5037
    },
    {
        "Id": 5720,
        "Date1": "2017-08-09T22:00:00Z",
        "LevelId": 4,
        "ParticipantId": 9915,
        "ID": 5720
    },
    {
        "Id": 5721,
        "Date1": "2017-08-10T22:00:00Z",
        "LevelId": 4,
        "ParticipantId": 9915,
        "ID": 5721
    },
    {
        "Id": 5722,
        "Date1": "2017-08-11T22:00:00Z",
        "LevelId": 2,
        "ParticipantId": 9915,
        "ID": 5722
    }
]
```

So the problem is having the item with the biggest DATE for one `LevelId`

Answer (score 0):

Cache The items for each level in an object where the key is the level and the value is the item with the biggest date so far.

```
var levels = [
{
    "Id": 5037,
    "Date1": "2016-06-22T22:00:00Z",
    "LevelId": 2,
    "ParticipantId": 9915,
    "ID": 5037
},
{
    "Id": 5720,
    "Date1": "2017-08-09T22:00:00Z",
    "LevelId": 4,
    "ParticipantId": 9915,
    "ID": 5720
},
{
    "Id": 5721,
    "Date1": "2017-08-10T22:00:00Z",
    "LevelId": 4,
    "ParticipantId": 9915,
    "ID": 5721
},
{
    "Id": 5722,
    "Date1": "2017-08-11T22:00:00Z",
    "LevelId": 2,
    "ParticipantId": 9915,
    "ID": 5722
    }
];

let isLastLevel = {};
for (let date of levels) {
   var isLast = isLastLevel[date.LevelId];  
    if ( (isLast && moment(date.Date1) > moment(isLast.Date1)) || !isLast) {
      isLastLevel[date.LevelId] = date;
    }
}
```

at the end "isLastLevel" will have a object with the biggest date for each level like this :

```
{
    2 : {
            "Id": 5722,
            "Date1": "2017-08-11T22:00:00Z",
            "LevelId": 2,
            "ParticipantId": 9915,
            "ID": 5722
    },
    4 : {
            "Id": 5721,
            "Date1": "2017-08-10T22:00:00Z",
            "LevelId": 4,
            "ParticipantId": 9915,
            "ID": 5721
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this wont work because I have to push first

Comment: I have not used an array anywhere so you don't have to push. According to your explanation this should definitely work. I had a bug for the first element but fixed that

Comment: Didn't work, i'm providing a solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution.

Sort, find and then push if last is not undefined

```
levels.sort(function (a, b) {
    return + new Date(b.Date1) - + new Date(a.Date1);
  });

  let lastLevelsTemp = new Array();
  let lastLevelsObjs = new Array();
  for (let index = 0; index < levels.length; index++) {
    const element = levels[index];
    if (lastLevelsTemp.length === 0) {
      lastLevelsTemp.push(element.LevelId);
      lastLevelsObjs.push(element);
    }
    else {
      let last = lastLevelsTemp.find((elm) => {
        return elm === element.LevelId;
      });
      if (last === undefined) {
        lastLevelsTemp.push(element.LevelId);
        lastLevelsObjs.push(element);
      }
    }
  }
```